# Does Grafana allow mysql as its backend in kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, grafana

I am trying to setup grafana on kubernetes and need to use mysql as its backend to store dashboards and its config instead of persistent volume.
Is there any way around to achieve it?

Tried grafana helm charts expecting any variable to use mysql as backend but could not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Grafana supports the Mysql, Postgress

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#database

You can set the value at **grafana.ini**

https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L682

```
grafana.ini:
    database:
      type: mysql
      host: ${host}
      user: ${username}
      password: ${password}
```

if looking forward to set environment variables

```
GF_DATABASE_TYPE=mysql
GF_DATABASE_HOST=host
GF_DATABASE_USER=username
GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
```